# when you configure build.gradle file and run the command ./gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, build.gradle

I'm getting below error in react native while running command

> .gradlew assebleRelease

> Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':generateReleaseBuildConfig'.

> Error while evaluating property 'applicationId' of task ':generateReleaseBuildConfig'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateReleaseBuildConfig' property 'applicationId'.
> > Failed to query the value of property 'applicationId'.
> > Manifest file does not exist: /home/nitin/Documents/reactnative/AwesomeProject/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date

I want generate apk file for the app

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, While adding signing configuration to your app's Gradle config, I configured the wrong build.gradle file. The final configuration step that needs to be done is to edit the `Android/app/build.gradle` file, which I am editing instead of `android/app/build.gradle`